# Excel Pivot Table Not Working when Using Formula

Tags: excel, pivot-chart

When creating values in a cell by using a formula: =IF(A2 = "RD", "RD", ""). Which says show value RD if RD and blank if not. I have three columns with different values, all set up the same way. When I try to pivot chart it, the data comes in but the count is not correct. All bars in the bar chart are exactly the same count even though the columns are filtered based on count of values (e.g., IF value is RD, count is based on RD and blanks not included). There are 37 RD values in column1, column 2 has 54 "RJ" values but bars in the chart reflect the same number which is the number of rows/cells in the table for each column. If I create the exact same chart using no formulas and use the pivot chart function, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that pivot tables do not automatically update in some specific circumstances. That's more to do with how Excel actually flags cells for calculation updates.

SHORT ANSWER. You need to get the pivot table to refresh. Shortcut for that is click the sheet with the pivot table that isn't updating, then go to "Data" and "Refresh All". Or faster, hit keys Alt, a, r, a. (sequentially, not simultaneously)

LONG ANSWER. Do some research on dependency trees in Excel. Understanding dependency trees will explain how Excel marks cells for updates and it will allow you to make much more efficient workbooks.